# Any way how to add new checkboxes into ListView depending on datarow of database?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I need basically something like this :

```
SqlCommand selectTags = new SqlCommand("select tag from Categories", cs);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectTags);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
cs.Open();
da.Fill(dt);
cs.Close();

CheckBox chkbb = new CheckBox();
list1.content


foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dr["tag"].ToString());

    Checkbox chk = new Checkbox into list1(list view) (This line supposed to be example.not working code. )
    chk.Content = dr["tag"].ToString();

}
```

Is it possible to create dynamical checkboxes depended on rows in sql database?

It can be added on page load etc.. I have no idea how to make something like this. Thank you so much for any help given.

added xaml of checkboxes

```
<ListView Name="list1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="307,52,0,0" Height="132" Width="293">

<CheckBox Content="inf" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="chkBoxInfo" Width="43"/>
<CheckBox Content="spo" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="chkBoxSp"/>
<CheckBox Content="war" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="chkBoxWar"/>
<CheckBox Content="cul" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="chkBoxCul" Height="14" Width="39"/>

</ListView>
```

Comment: @mm8 provided the right answer but are you familiar with data binding? Seeing your code I suppose not. Here are some helpfull links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf

Comment: Yea I need to learn binding and also MVVM. These things are really new to me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set or bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` to `dt.DefaultView`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlCommand selectTags = new SqlCommand("select tag from Categories", cs))
{
    cs.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectTags))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    cs.Close();
}
list1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

..and use an `ItemTemplate` or a `CellTemplate` to display the `CheckBox`:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding tag}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. Can you please explain me that?

Comment: One more question maybe. How do I add all checkboxes into foreach loop? _foreach (CheckBox item in list1.Items)
            {
                if (item.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    list.Add("CategoryMulti like '%" + item.Content.ToString() + "%'");
                }
            }_

Is not currently working with databinding

Comment: The thing is that you only defined the CheckBoxes in the view, i.e. in the XAML markup. You should read up on MVVM and separation of concerns.

Comment: Aha, that means that I cant work with them now? Or can I use them for some logic?

Comment: Bind to the `IsChecked` property to a column of your `DataTable`. You then check which rows that are checked by iterating through the rows.

Comment: I was really trying to find how to do that. But I have still no idea. :(

Comment: @Cabry: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.